Question regarding the properties of an automorphism group of a Sylow P subgroup
The context for this question has to do with proving: Groups of order $pq$ with $p < q$ have a normal subgroup of order $q$ and are cyclic iff $q$ is not congruent to $1$ mod $p$. I will leave out the earlier steps of the proof as I understand them. Here is the part that confuses me

... So $ G = Q \rtimes P$, This gives a homomorphism φ $: P → Aut(Q)$. Moreover, $ Aut(Q) = (Z/qZ)^× \cong Z/(q − 1)Z$. The map φ is trivial unless $q \cong 1$ (mod p). If it is trivial, then $G = P ×Q = Z/pZ×Z/qZ \cong Z/pqZ$.

I understand how we get the homomorphism, but I do not understand why the Automorphism group of Q is isomorphic to $(Z/qZ)^×$. I see why $(Z/qZ)^× \cong Z/(q-1)Z$ (I mean thats pretty obvious), but I really do not understand how the map is trivial unless p is congruent to 1 mod p. If it is trivial I know that this is just the direct product, so everything after that makes sense for me. Any Help is appreciated. Ive ran into a similar problem before and just couldnt figure it out.

The isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}/(q-1)$ is considerably less obvious than the statement you're asking about! Just think about what an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/q$ can do. It sends $1$ to some other number. What does that imply about where it sends everything else?

@QiaochuYuan  is it because Q is cyclic of order q and an automorphism of Q maps a generator onto another generator?

Yes. Can you write out the argument from here?

@QiaochuYuan Well for Z/q we have the q-1 generators 1,2,...,q-1. The automorphisms are determined by where we map 1, since if 1 gets sent to 2, 2 gets sent to 4 mod q etc. So we have that |Aut(Q)| = q-1 = | (Z/qZ)^{\times}|. but im having trouble coming up with an isomorphism between them. I was thinking something like sending \alpha_k \to k where \alpha_k is the Automorphism sending 1 to k, but this isnt a homomorphism so it doesnt work

So you agree that an automorphism must send a generator to a generator and is determined by where we map $1$. So let $\varphi(1) = a$. What is $\varphi(2)$? What is $\varphi(k)$?

@QiaochuYuan well (2) = a + a, so (k) = a + ... + a (k times) mod q, or alternatively (k) = (1) + ... + (1) (k times) mod q. I think the law of composition in Aut(Q) is whats confusing me

Great, so we've established that every automorphism has the form $\phi(k) = ak$ for some $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/q)^{\times}$. Do you agree? What happens when you compose two functions of this form?

Yes. if ()= for some  in the multiplicative group and (k)=bk for some b in the multiplicative group, we have that ((k)) = abk for ab in the multiplicative group. I can see how this is an isomorphism (finally, thank you), I am just having a really hard time seeing how to define a homomorphism into the multiplicative group. I assume we have to use exponents somehow but im not seeing it. I must be overlooking something obvious here

The isomorphism to the multiplicative group sends $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/q)^{\times}$ to the map $\phi(k) = ak$. You have just computed that this is a homomorphism! Moreover we already established that it's a bijection. No exponents necessary. Do you agree?

Oh i see now why its a homomorphism. If we have ()= and (k) = bk we have F(ab) = some map x such that x(k) = abk. Then if we look at F(a)F(b) we have the composition of  and  which at k is just abk. There we go. Earlier i got to akbk and was like thats not abk and stopped. I think my issue was that i jumped past the Automorphism and evaluated right away. Thank you very much for helping me through it, i appreciate it a lot. Now im going to try and see why its trivial unless p is congruent to 1 mod p.

Yes, that's right, we need to compose $k \mapsto ak$ and $k \mapsto bk$ to get $k \mapsto abk$, rather than multiplying pointwise to get $akbk$. The most difficult part of this argument is getting good notation for everything, I think. You're welcome!

For $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)$, the image $\sigma(1)$ determines the whole $\sigma$,  as $\sigma(k)=k\sigma(1)\pmod q$ for $k=1,\dots,q-1$ (and, of course, $\sigma(0)=0$). Accordingly, the order of $\sigma$ is equal to the multiplicative order of $\sigma(1)$. And $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^\times$ has an element of order $p$ if $p\mid q-1$, precisely because $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic of order $q-1$.
On the other hand, if $p\nmid q-1$, then $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ cannot embed into  $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)$, and hence you are left with the trivial homomorphism, only.
(Btw, it is way more obvious $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)\cong (\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^\times$ than $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^\times\cong\mathbb Z/(q-1)\mathbb Z$.)

Thanks for the answer. Why is it more obvious than the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/q \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}/(q-1)\mathbb{Z}$? They are both cyclic of order q-1. Do we need to know more? @Kan't

@froitmi, to prove that $(\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z)^\times$ has an element of order $q-1$ (namely, that it is cyclic) you have to go through one of the several proofs surveied in the following resource, none of them I can say is "easy" (to me, at least): https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf. I think you are taking for granted something that actually it is not.

Ok yes thank you. I have done this proof before so I was assuming it. I should have made that more clear. Thank you! :)

An automorphism of $Q$ sends generators to generators and is determined by where it sends 1. Therefore we can set up a group homomorphism between $Aut(Q)$ and $(Z/qZ)^{\times}$ by sending an automorphism $\alpha \in Aut(Q)$ to $\alpha(1) = \bar{a} \in (Z/qZ)^{\times}$. Let F denote this map. Let $\alpha$ be as above and let $\beta \in Aut(Q)$ such that $\beta(1) = \bar{b}$. Then $F(\alpha \beta) = \alpha(\beta(1)) = \alpha( \beta(1) \cdot 1) = \beta(1) \alpha(1) = \alpha(1) \beta(1)$. Thus we have proven that $F$ is a group homomorphism. Note: we get that $\alpha(\beta(1) \cdot 1)) = \beta(1) \alpha(1)$ because this is simply the fact $\phi(g^m) =  \phi(g)^m$ for some group homomorphism $\phi$ (written additively). Checking that F is injective / surjective after this point is quite trivial.
If φ is trivial, then the kernal is the entirety of P and we have that the homomorphic image is just the trivial automorphism. This is fine. But, suppose φ is not trivial. Then the kernal is not the entirety of P, but since P is a cyclic group of order p, the kernal must have order 1 (must divide p). This implies that the homomorphic image has order p. But the image must divide the order of $Aut(Q)$ since its a subgroup, but this group has order $q-1$. We can see that $p$ will only divide $q-1$ in this case if $q \cong 1 (mod p)$ and thus we can see that φ is forced to be trivial unless this condition holds.
